# I will or I would have left by this time tomorrow?

Tags: tenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Will have” vs. “Would have”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11679/will-have-vs-would-have)

I read somewhere that it is "I will". Which rule is this? Where can I find these rules for tenses?

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another).

Comment: @Kit: Wow! I had never seen this question/answer before!  When I was working on structuring a new language, I drew up a chart very similar to that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I will" means it is the current plan or expectation. "I would" implies it is *no longer* the expectation:

> If I get the tickets tonight, I will have left by this time tomorrow.

vs.

> If the tickets had not been canceled, I would have left by this time
>   tomorrow.

**EDIT:**
One more case that I had forgotten, the pure subjunctive or counterfactual, where the main clause has *never* been the expectation:

> If Detroit were a nice place to live, I would have left for there by this time
>   tomorrow.

Comment: You're right.  I forgot about the if-then possibility.

Comment: Can you tell me whether these sentences are grammatical: 1) "If the meeting finished on time, he would have caught the 3.15 train." 2) "If it rains tomorrow it would make things very difficult for us."

Comment: @MrReality — the first sentence is fine; many native English speakers would use the conditional as you did in the second, but I think simple future would be preferable.